# How should I insert decimal values via cqlsh (DecimalSerializer.deserialize error when attempting)?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

In cqlsh I'm trying to insert a record with:

```
INSERT INTO data 
(order_id,order_ts,transaction_id,transaction_discount,transaction_qty,
transaction_total,
product_category,product_profit,product_upc,product_name,product_price,
product_distributor,
store_id,store_name,store_state,store_region,id) 

values ('YBC8RWE18',1368438171000,'LQKLVVI4E', 0, 1, 140.72, 
'Office Supplies', 12.42, 
'YT8899H3357', 'Casio USB Model FX-9860GII', 140.72, 'QR0', '2YOYWMR28Q', 
'BigLots', 'AZ', 
'Southwest', 2259a88e-b62d-4625-a86e-b86d77418a34 );
```

Looks fine, but I'm getting a number exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:190)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.DecimalSerializer.deserialize(DecimalSerializer.java:41)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.DecimalSerializer.deserialize(DecimalSerializer.java:26)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.compose(AbstractType.java:142)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DecimalType.compare(DecimalType.java:46)
```

Looks like `DecimalSerializer.deserialize` is the real issue here. If I try to surround the decimals in quotes (worth a shot, I thought) I get:

`Bad Request: Invalid STRING constant (140.72) for product_price of type decimal`

So that didn't help. What do I need to do to insert a decimal? Should I post up the COLUMNFAMILY def?

Here's the DESCRIBE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id uuid,
  order_id text,
  order_ts timestamp,
  product_category text,
  product_distributor text,
  product_name text,
  product_price decimal,
  product_profit decimal,
  product_upc text,
  store_id text,
  store_name text,
  store_region text,
  store_state text,
  transaction_discount decimal, 
  transaction_id text,
  transaction_qty int,
  transaction_total decimal,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If I take off the quotes around 140.72 I get: `Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.` and the logs show the `deserialize` error. If I try to just insert a few columns it's fine -- until I try to insert the product_price field.

Comment: What is the **DESCRIBE TABLE data** output in cqlsh?

Comment: What version of cassandra are you using? I just tried it against 2.0.8 and it works fine.

Comment: @mikea 2.0.8, fresh install yesterday. `[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]`

Comment: @jcollum that's very strange because I just created your table and ran your insert without any error. Can you try inserting just that column.

Comment: I have a bunch of indexes and I'm getting `Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.` when I do what I expect to be a valid insert, is it possible that the rpc_timeout is too low out of the box?

Comment: (tried looking for the rpc timeout in the yaml config, didn't see it)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got any answers, but did get some help.

The answer to this one isn't very satisfying. None of the errors really clued me in to what was going on, but I thought: well, there's really only a few moving parts here: the table def and the indexes. So I dropped the table and recreated it without indexes. Fixed the issue. Recreated the indexes and the issue was still fixed. So perhaps the indexes were messed up?

Comment: @jcolumm what indexes did you have on the table?

Comment: I have indexes on all the fields. I'm evaluating Cassandra for arbitrary aggregations, e.g. "what's the total sales for Pokemon cards in Arizona on Tuesday afternoon of last week?"

Answer (score 0):

Got the same exception even without index on the table. If you look into the stack trace in the constructor of BigInteger `public BigInteger(byte[] val)`, the exception are thrown when the passed in byte array is empty. Maybe there are bugs in Cassandra driver to deserialize decimal? However, there are following comments are interesting:

> Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

Will the Cassandra driver guarantee the passed byte array is big-endian? The solution could be use other types like `double` instead.